# Angular4: How do I generate an XML file and return it to the browser

Tags: angular, firebase

Forgive me, for I am relatively new to Angular 4, but I am stuck on something...

I would like when a user goes to https://example.com/sitemap in their web browser...

1. Data is queried from Firebase
2. An XML structure is built from this data
3. **(THIS IS THE ONE I CAN NOT FIGURE OUT)** XML is returned to the user's web browser with a content type
       of *application/xml* (i.e. the `<head>`, `<body>`, `<script>` and
       other contents of my src/index.html, should **not** be included in
       the response).

I have done plenty of Googling and searching Stack Overflow -- but everything I find is just about ingesting an XML document, or writing XML to a page, but not writing an XML document back to the web browser.

Working examples would be appreciated, as I am still learning all the in's and out's of Angular 4.

Comment: Looks like the server is throwing an exception, returning an HTML page instead. Step through the code on your server side, check the final data being submitted back, if possible...  I'm not fluent with Firebase.

Comment: @Dayan, thanks.   I am not even there yet.  I don't know HOW to return a response that doesn't have all the view stuff wrapped around it.  So it is more of a question of method, than debugging a problem?

Comment: Are you trying to build a XML interface with Angular?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code : sample response plz of application/xml

Comment: I am basically trying to generate a live sitemap.xml for use by Google.   My pages / blog entries are all hosted within Firebase, so I need to query that to get URLs, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nobody could seem to offer an answer, I created my rather own hacky answer.   As I am using Firebase for hosting, I leveraged Firebase Storage API to save off my sitemap.xml file and then forward the browser to the just generated document.

Comment: Does this really work for you? I generate a sitemap.xml in backend as well and then forward the browser to that sitemap, but google still gives me an error (sitemap is in html, because angular loads html before forwarding). Can you please share more info about your hack?

Comment: Yes, this works.   I have a "Success" in webmaster tools from as recent as November 26.  

You need to handle the redirect from your web server, not from Angular.   You could do this in Nginx or IIS using a rewrite rule.   Or, if you use Cloudflare you can setup a Page Rule.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code Can you please let me know how did you write rewrite rule in IIS because I am searching for same thing ?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code And also how to redirect to other url from angular 9 to match the case of rewrite rule ?

Comment: @Darshana  I left Angular behind at around Angular 5 -- the complexity and drawbacks (like the above) made it not worth it for me.   For simple sites, there are plenty of static site generators out there.  For everything more complex there is .NET Core.  :-)     

But... you basically you just need to look for requests to the sitemap.xml and do a 301 redirect to any page that spits out content in the sitemap spec with an XML content type.   This can be done with IIS Url Rewrite module, web.config entry (see my site for examples of those), or a frontend like Cloudflare.